# Create filter type of folder/mailbox with Dovecot

Tags: email-server, imap, dovecot, filtering

Note: various people/cultures/background call these things differently, I will call them folders (as seen by a mail client) so most readers should understand.

The question is: with Dovecot is it possible to create a folder which stores not actual emails but acts as a filter. E.g. I can specify (note: pseudo-code!) `to:john.smith,search-inside:*` and when a user clicks on that folder in their email client they will see all emails matching the above search criteria?

Comment: This is called a "search folder" and its usually implemented on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dovecot supports server-side [virtual folders](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/Virtual); filters are specified as conditions for the IMAP SEARCH command.

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot offers the pigeonhole Sieve implementation; anything that can do, you are free to use.

However, selecting messages based on arbitrary criteria is a client function, not a server one.

I'd have to say "no".